# MsTeams how to disable deletion of files

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

My question is about ms-teams. 
How do I prevent deleting files from ms teams by guests or members. By the way, i am working with the free version.

Untill now i did not succeed. I looked at channel and document level but could not find a solution. Please help me out.